Index / Match Formula Spill
My goal is to create a formula that will search through a set of cells until it finds a value, when it finds a value in that selection, it will display the column header.  For example, the formula in my attached example is in AU6.  Bellow is a summary of the formula.
Formula:
=INDEX($O$4:$AQ6,,MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0))
I want the formula to search for a cell that has a value in O4 to AQ6 (column headers are in the 4th row).  When a value is found, it will return the name of the column header.
I tried using the INDEX and MATCH functions to get the column header name, but I can't figure out why the formula spills the value found into A8.  For this, I don't need the value the formula found to be returned at all, just the column header.
Ultimately, I want to copy the formula into each cell of AU from AU6 all the way to AU103.  The spilling creates a mess and I don't know how to fix it.  Hope this makes sense and thank you for your time :)
If you prefer to work with the file, I'd be happy to provide it if there is a way to do that there.


I am not sure whether it is just a typo or you need some syntax docs on INDEX.
But here is the link that explains when INDEX returns a single cell, when it returns an entire row or entire column.
https://exceljet.net/functions/index-function
In short, you can specify row_num = 1 in your formula to fix this:
=INDEX($O$4:$AQ6,1,MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0))

Let's debug the formula:
=INDEX($O$4:$AQ6,,MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0))

The MATCH function MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0) returns 8
Note that this part of the formula only searches for the value 2,492.00 within the range $O6:$AQ6, not $O$4:$AQ6 as mentioned in the question.

The Index function becomes =INDEX($O$4:$AQ6,,8) which returns the entire column 8 of the range $O6:$AQ6, this is because the array and row_num provided within the INDEX function are $O4:$AQ6 and 0 respectively (using 0 or nothing as row_num returns the entire column)


To return only the corresponding value of the header use this formula:
= INDEX($O$4:$AQ$4,1,MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0))
or this formula:
= INDEX($O$4:$AQ$4,MATCH($AT6,$O6:$AQ6,0)) (works in 365 don't remember if it works in prior versions)
see INDEX function
